# How to install add-on on a remote Firefox webdriver?

Tags: python, selenium, firefox

[`install_addon`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_firefox/selenium.webdriver.firefox.webdriver.html#selenium.webdriver.firefox.webdriver.WebDriver.install_addon) is a method on the Firefox webdriver, but I'm running tests remotely. How can I install an add-on to a driver like the following:

```
driver = webdriver.Remote(
    command_executor=SELENIUM_URL,
    desired_capabilities=webdriver.DesiredCapabilities.FIREFOX
)
```

? It looks like creating a `webdriver.FirefoxProfile()` and using `add_extension()` should work, but [it's currently broken](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/4093).

The [use case](https://github.com/l0b0/insecure-links-highlighter/issues/3) is testing the effect of Firefox add-on manifest.json's `all_frames` property.

Answer (score 1):

Аfter a long search and visits on this topic from google i found solution

Install addon in you Firefox profile from browser, save it and set him into webdriver options.

## Firefox profile creating

1. Open you `firefox` browser
2. Go to `about:profiles`
3. Create a New Profile
4. Launch browser with created profile
5. Install addons what you need

## Export profile

1. Open root directory of your firefox profile (see in in `about:profiles` in `Root Directory` section)
2. Copy folder into you project

## Python

```py
from selenium.webdriver import FirefoxOptions, FirefoxProfile, Remote

# init options object
options = FirefoxOptions()

# init profile object with path to you profile
profile = FirefoxProfile('{path_to_your_profile_folder}')

# set profile into options
options.profile = profile

# init you Remote browser with created options (commented arguments for example)
driver = Remote(
    options=options,
    # command_executor= ..., 
    # desired_capabilities=...
)
```

---

It`s  works for me. The disadvantage of this solution is the presence of a folder with a profile that needs to be stored somewhere